# Dictionary of weak and non-weak references

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, weak-references

I have a custom type `MyClass` and a factory class `Factory` that creates objects of type `MyClass` upon request.

The `Factory` stores created objects in a dictionary because *objects are expensive to create* and there are times when same object can be asked to be created multiple times. Each object with the same tag must be created one time only.

```
class MyObject
{
    // .. not important
}

class Factory
{
    private Dictionary<int, MyObject> m_objects = new Dictionary<int, MyObject>();

    public MyObject CreateObject(int tag, params object[] parameters)
    {
        MyObject obj;
        if (!m_objects.TryGetValue(tag, out obj))
        {
            obj = new MyObject();
            // .. some initialization
            m_objects.Add(tag, obj);
        }

        return obj;
    }
}
```

Objects *might be and might be not stored somewhere outside* `Factory` for unknown amount of time. Objects *might be changed* after creation. There are times when `Factory` stores reference to an object and the object is not stored anywhere else.

Now I want let garbage collector to do its job. I want objects **not stored anywhere outside `Factory` and not changed** to be collected.

My first thought was to use weak references for values in dictionary inside `Factory` but it seems like this approach does not handle "changed and unreferenced" case.

How should I store created objects in a dictionary so they are:

- Could be garbage collected
- Are not garbage collected when not referenced but changed?

Comment: How about just creating an additional dictionary into which you put all changed objects?

Comment: @CodesInChaos thanks, it's interesting. But dictionary can be very large (tens of thousands pairs) and I would prefer to not duplicate it if I may.

Comment: That'd be a few hundred kB. If it's a desktop application, that should be OK.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Please post your comment as answer so I could accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expanding on CodesInChaos' answer, I think you're on the right track using weak references in your original `Dictionary` and I think it makes sense to use a second data structure - probably a `HashSet` would work well here - that just holds references to objects which have been changed.

Remember, storing a *reference* to an object is cheap. I'd think you'd have to be on the order of millions or billions of references before it starts becoming a concern.